# I am implementing DocuSign API using ASP.Net, but when sending envelope and redirect to DocuSign site evrytime necessary to login to DocuSign Site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, docusignapi

```
 Uri oauthLoginUrl = clsDocuSignAPI.GetAuthorizationUri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntegratorKey"], scopes, RedirectURI, OAuth.CODE, null);
 Response.Redirect(oauthLoginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
```

> Can we get authorization code without redirecting to DocuSign or without authenticated at DocuSign site. I do not want to redirect from my application to DocuSign. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [JWT (JSON Web Tokens)](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) for Authentication instead of Auth Code Grant.
With JWT you still need to get consent once, it has to be done only once ever per user that is sending envelopes or you can use admin consent for an entire org.

If you are using C#, I suggest using the C# SDK which does most of the work for you. You just need an RSA Keypair and use the private key in your code.

Recommend you use [this source code](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/Common/JWTAuth.cs) for JWT after you obtained consent.

```
    var apiClient = new ApiClient();
    string ik = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntegrationKey"];
    string userId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userId"];
    string authServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthServer"];
    string rsaKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RSAKey"];
    OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(ik,
                    userId,
                    authServer,
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rsaKey),
                    1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DocuSign sender is operating your application, then the InfoSec recommended technique is to use Authorization Code grant. Save the refresh token and use it the next time the sender uses your application. Use both `signature` and `extended` scopes.

This way, if the user uses your application once a month or more often, they will never need to authenticate again with DocuSign. (The refresh token lasts a month. And you get a new one when the user shows up again via the refresh operation.)

Note that the user is not "logging in" to DocuSign. Rather, they are "connecting" or "authenticating" your app with DocuSign.